# Where can I find information about upcoming special issues in a field of study?

Tags: publications, journals

How can I find information about upcoming special issues related to a special field of study? There are good websites for upcoming conferences but I could not find any place to search for special issues.

Comment: Do you already known [WikiCPF](http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/)? It aims to be a sematic wiki for CfP (both conferences and journals). You can search for your favorite topics there!

Comment: @dgraziotin Thanks. I thought it only indexes conferences, but it awesome for special issues as well.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the two sources mentioned by William, I can add *professional societies* or their equivalent. It is usually these that organize meetings that result in special issues. It is rare (may differ between disciplines) that journals themselves, unless they somehow specialize, provide open special issues around a theme. Usually, it is then by invitation, or papers emanating from a workshop or symposia etc.

Hence, looking for especial issues may be a dead end and you should be looking for activities that lead to such issues.

As a final note, the term special issue signals an unregular issue in a scientific journal open for submission of manuscripts. Many conferences issue proceedings but then the prerequisite is usually attendance at the meeting and presentation of the paper there.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no website referencing special issues from different journals. However, I see two potential ways to stay informed :

1. Make a list of the good journals in your field, then browse their website for information (might take some time, especially to stay up to date).
2. Use social networks. Many journals have twitter accounts and/or blogs and they are likely to advertise their special issues through these media.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I have found one website to get special issue information regarding sci/scie indexed journal. Please go through the following website.

- https://research.com/

Comment: Welcome to academia.SE. It is a good practice to indicate whether you are affiliated with the website or not.

Comment: @TommiBrander no, I am not affiliated with this website.